# Hostlistener does not respond to arrow keys

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 component and in the middle of that I listen for keys:

```
  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log(event);
  }
```

I'm not getting any notification of arrow keys, enter keys work, as do normal keys.

I've read in this post that I can add a window.event:

[Angular2 Navigation using Arrow Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109173/angular2-navigation-using-arrow-keys)
That seems to be the only post on the subject.

Whilst I can use that solution (and admittedly I'm sure it would work), it doesn't seem very "angular" to me. Also what element should I put this on?

Why am I not getting notification of arrow keys? They are a keypress aren't they?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd need to use `keydown` for arrow keys.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log(event);
  }
```

keypress event represents a character being typed, and arrows are not characters so they won't trigger keypress